# Sec-WebSocket-Key returned from server does not match expected response

Tags: java, websocket

I got some hot stuffs going on this morning.
I was kind of proud to add some websocket features in a swing client to communicate with the server using tyrus-standalone-client version 1.12.
All the tests did run successfully.
Yesterday I released the new version of the swing client. A couple of our customers could start the client anymore due to the following error:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Sec-WebSocket-Key returned from server does not match expected response.

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.SecKey.validateServerKey(SecKey.java:139)

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.Handshake.validateServerResponse(Handshake.java:187)

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processUpgradeResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:516)

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.handleSwitchProtocol(TyrusClientEngine.java:340)

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:277)

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:346)

            at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:315)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)

            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)

            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have not been able to really figure out what the cause of the issue might be since that same client is running successfully with other customers of mine.
My only clue is the java version. A customer who encouters the problem is using java 1.8.0_71. I have tested on java 1.8.0_73 and 1.8.0_45 without problem.

Thanks